# Smalltalk: Is there something like "is in" or "is contained"?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm having trouble with Smalltalk. Is there some operator like "is in" or "is contained / included"?

I have classes Student and Exam (with attribute student) and collections StudentsList and ExamsList. In the ExamsList, I would like to show all instances of class Exam that meet the criteria that their student (object set as value of attribute student) is contained in collection StudentsList.

Something like the following code, but it does not work:

`ExamsList list: (Exam allInstances select: [ :ex | (StudentsList includes: ex student) ]).`

Could you think of some elegant solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks reasonable. What exactly is not working?

Comment: `#(1 2 3) includes: 2` answers `true`, so yes, there is something like "is in".

Answer (score 3):

Even though your question lacks some information, there are a few comments that might help.

1. If your naming convention is consistent and `ExamsList` is a class, then `StudentsList` must be a class too. In that case your code doesn't work because classes do not understand the message `#includes:`, which is intended to be sent to subinstances of `Collection`.
2. Assuming my guess is applicable, I would point out that it is not a good idea to have a class for every collection of objects. So, instead of having the class `ExamsList`, you should add a class variable `Exams` to the class `Exam`, initialized to a `Set` and store there every instance of `Exam` that you want to preserve for future queries.
3. In the same way, you should add a class variable `Students` to the class `Student` and get rid of `StudentsList`.
4. With this design every new instance that matters should be saved in the corresponding collection held by the class (see 6 below for a hint on how to do this). This would eliminate the need for enumerating `#allInstances`.
5. In any case, you should understand that `#allInstances` is a system message, i.e., it is not intended for querying objects in the realm of your model as it belongs in much lower level of abstraction. Note that `#allInstances` will collect instances that for whatever reason (tests, examples, open debuggers or inspectors, etc.) may still be around without being part of your model.
6. If every `Exam` has a `Student`, you could store an `Exam` in the `Exams` collection whenever you assign it to the designated `Student`, something on the lines of

```
   Exam >> forStudent: aStudent
     Exams add: self.
     student := aStudent
```

(`student` is an ivar of `Exam`, and `self` represents the instance with concrete questions)